# Was PETA's support of lab grown meat that used calf blood vegan?

Tags: is-it-vegan, animal-by-products, cultured-meat

PETA [supported](https://www.peta.org/blog/taste-testers-love-first-bite-lab-grown-meat/) lab grown meat that used fetal calf serum even though it apparently may have involved [slaughter](https://www.theguardian.com/business/2015/sep/05/meat-without-murder-modern-meadow). Is this support of a process that may involve slaughter considered vegan?

Comment: I doubt you will get anything more than an opinion here. And, as it is, that is not the format that SE approves of very much. I think PETA backed this up from mainly utilitarian point of view - it can, with loads of research, vastly reduce animals killed by humans for food. ON the other hand, I believe this is not something vegan, since the death is involved, and it does not have to be, but people are stubborn about their stomachs and PETA took 'better than nothing' approach. Also note that PETA is not the authority in all things vegan and that many of us do often not agree with what it does.

Comment: I tried to reword your last sentence, let me know if tha'ts not what you wanted.

Comment: Curiously, PETA is _not_ backing the Impossible Burger because [Impossible Foods engaged in animal testing](https://metro.co.uk/2018/07/29/peta-isnt-backing-the-vegan-burger-that-bleeds-7770845/).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By definition, vegans do not use any animal product, food or otherwise

https://www.vegansociety.com/go-vegan/definition-veganism

> Veganism is a way of living which seeks to exclude, as far as is
>   possible and practicable, all forms of exploitation of, and cruelty
>   to, animals for food, clothing or any other purpose.

Although I know many Vegans, I do not personally know any Vegan that would condone "lab grown meat that used fetal calf serum" or support PETA's position on this topic.

Although there may be an exception, I am going to say the consensus opinion would be to avoid any use of any animal product, including "lab grown meat that used fetal calf serum".

Answer (score 4):

If it took killing to produce, I wouldn't eat it. That would go against my morality.

However, there is also the bigger picture here. Millions of animals die everyday just for the consumption of their flesh. If one calf being killed is going to stop many more from not being killed, I can understand why a group dedicated to animal welfare would support it.

That said, there are other groups/companies that are making "lab grown meat" without killing, though they still do initially involve at least taking muscle from living animals as far as I know.